# Efficient Frontier Derivation: why minimize half the portfolio variance instead of just the variance?

Tags: optimization, modern-portfolio-theory

In Robert Merton's derivation of the efficient frontier of a portfolio, he minimizes 
$\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 $ over the investment weights in each asset, where $\sigma^2$ represents portfolio variance. I am confused why the function he minimizes is half the variance, instead of just the variance. It doesn't make a difference in calculations, but I cannot figure out why he (and all other derivations) do this.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about this formula:

$$U(w) = w'\mu - \frac{1}{2} \lambda w' \Sigma w = w'\mu - \frac{1}{2} \lambda \sigma_\omega^2$$

where $\sigma_\omega^2$ denotes the portfolio variance for a portfolio with weights $\omega$.

Dividing by two is purely done for convenience, optimizing this formula requires taking the derivative with respect to $\omega$ and setting it to $0$. When the derivative is taken the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ is canceled by the square.

See this [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/8405/848) on more information on setting $\lambda$.

Comment: Clear answer - there is nothing more to it.

Comment: does having 1/2 in the front of the objective function give a different solution for $w$ than when there is no 1/2? If so, how to account for the discrepancy between the two approaches

Comment: @develarist This might be material for a different question. The answer is that it depends: you can change $\lambda$ to compensate. With fixed $\lambda$, yes the result will change and I expect the change to be significant in all cases encountered in practice.

Comment: so if we forget about the coefficient $\lambda$ and look at the more practical non-utility portfolio optimization,then $\min w'\Sigma w \neq \min (1/2) w'\Sigma w$

Comment: I don't follow the argument, what happened to $\omega' \mu$ in your equation?

Comment: this new formula is just the global minimum variance portfolio (full-investment constraint is hidden) that singles out the portfolio variance term that also appeared in the utility approach. you would expect that (1/2) should also be retained at the front for convenience, but in industry it is not?

Comment: Please ask a new question, this is getting too long.